# crash on fpu instructions and asm code do not work

Tags: c, assembly, x86, calling-convention

sorry for my weak english

im trying to improve my asm abilities and i have found easy
entry point to working on it by using machine code routines
from c code

i am using it in such way

```
    char asmRoutineData2[]  =
    {
    0xC8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,         // enter 0, 0
    0xB8, 0xff, 0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00,    // mov eax, 65538
    0xC9,                           // leave
    0xc3                            // ret
    };

 int (*asmRoutine)(void) = (int (*)(void)) asmRoutineData;
 int ret = asmRoutine();
```

and it works pretty excellent for some routines - such as above

some other do not work:

1)i got trouble and I cannot obtain value passed by stack

such procedure

```
    char asmRoutine_body[]  =
    {

    0xC8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,      //enter
    0x8B, 0x45, 0x08,          // mov eax, [ebp+8]
    0xC9,               //leave
    0xC3
    };
```

and

```
 int ( *asmRoutine)(int, int, int) = ( int (*)(int, int, int)) asmRoutine_body;
 int ret = asmRoutine(77,66,55);
```

should work as far as i know but it does not

i looked up in asm generated by kompiler and it seem to be correct

```
mov       eax,offset _asmRoutineData
push      55
push      66
push      77
call      eax
add       esp,12  


    _asmRoutineData label byte
db  200     //enter
db  0
db  0
db  0       
db  139     //  mov  eax, dword [ebp+8H]  ; 8B. 45, 08
db  69
db  8
db  201       //leave
db  195        //ret
```

do not know what is wrong (returns other values than my expected 77 (or 66 or 55 for ebp+12 ebp+16)

2) second trouble is that this way of calling machine code 
 works for arithmetic instructions form me but it crashes aplication 
(some way of system exception)  on fpu or sse instructions

why? and what i should do to make it work for me (i would love write assembly 
routines such way)

fir

//EDIT

this is sse routine that should get a float4* vector a and b
make dot product and put result into float4* c 
(float4 is a struct or table of 4 floats)

(strange couse it should anly get two vectors and return a float
by eax but i got if form internet possibly and got no moment to 
test and rewrite it)

```
    /*
    enter   0, 0                                    ; 0034 _ C8, 0000, 00
    mov     eax, dword [ebp+8H]                     ; 0038 _ 8B. 45, 08
    mov     ebx, dword [ebp+0CH]                    ; 003B _ 8B. 5D, 0C
    mov     ecx, dword [ebp+10H]                    ; 003E _ 8B. 4D, 10
    movups  xmm0, oword [eax]                       ; 0041 _ 0F 10. 00
    movups  xmm1, oword [ebx]                       ; 0044 _ 0F 10. 0B
    mulps   xmm0, xmm1                              ; 0047 _ 0F 59. C1
    movhlps xmm1, xmm0                              ; 004A _ 0F 12. C8
    addps   xmm1, xmm0                              ; 004D _ 0F 58. C8
    movaps  xmm0, xmm1                              ; 0050 _ 0F 28. C1
    shufps  xmm1, xmm1, 1                           ; 0053 _ 0F C6. C9, 01
    addss   xmm0, xmm1                              ; 0057 _ F3: 0F 58. C1
    movss   dword [ecx], xmm0                       ; 005B _ F3: 0F 11. 01
    leave                                           ; 005F _ C9
    ret                                             ; 0060 _ C3
    */

    char asmDot_body[] =
    {
     0xC8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,

     0x8B, 0x45, 0x08,
     0x8B, 0x5D, 0x0C,
     0x8B, 0x4D, 0x10,

     0x0F, 0x10, 0x00,
     0x0F, 0x10, 0x0B,

     0x0F, 0x59, 0xC1,
     0x0F, 0x12, 0xC8,
     0x0F, 0x58, 0xC8,
     0x0F, 0x28, 0xC1,
     0x0F, 0xC6, 0xC9, 0x01,
     0xF3, 0x0F, 0x58, 0xC1,
     0xF3, 0x0F, 0x11, 0x01,
     0xC9,
     0xC3
     };


    void (*asmAddSSE)(float4*, float4*, float4*) = (void (*)(float4*, float4*, float4*)) asmDot_body;

    float4 a = {1,2,1,0};
    float4 b = {1,2,3,0};
    float4 c = {0,0,0,0};

    asmAddSSE(&a,&b,&c);
```

//EDIT L8R

FOUND IT! and it works extremally cool & great 
 (passing arguments and also fpu and even sse) 
 Im happy

tnx necrolis for stating that it was working on yr system,

I began to try with compiler switches tu set up alignment and 
also disable some and it was -pr (use fastcall ) that was 
enebled and i should to turn it off

(got two compile.bat's - one for normal compilation and 
second for olso generating assembly and no -pr switch in the 
second so asm code i wrote abowe is okay - but my normal 
compile.bat generated fastcall calls ant it goes bum!)

Comment: You aren't using assembler. You are writing machine code. Get an assembler.

Comment: This might get you started: http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html

Comment: How about stepping through your code instruction by instruction in a debugger? That would tell you what's wrong with your code.

Comment: got no debugger :/ also i know thai i am writing machine code - got no inline assembly and do not want to fight with standalone assembly (it is much more complex) Some other ideas how to debug and fix it? i got no idea whats wrong

Comment: @user982377 Did you just say that assembly is *more complex* than literally writing machine code?

Comment: yes, using assembly is *MUCH MORE* complex (need to read in large manuals, fighting with directives fighting with linker - got some hard troubles already once ago with obj formats and proper linking - it is also much slower to edit-to-test really) such way is easy as 1 2 3 - opcodes i can find in some dissasembly listings i have got, also do not want to write large things in assembly only a few routines  - i also want to understend how assembly looks like on machine code level - so i know what i am saying when i m saying that i would write exactly such way not ussing standalone assembly

Comment: Good luck. You stand alone in believing that writing machine code is easier than writing assembler. You are unlikely to get much help since the rest of the world long ago gave up writing machine code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your very first problem is you assume that the code is executable, if you are lucky, DEP is off and you can execute code from your stack, but generally (99.99% of the time) you **need** to allocate executable memory to do this. Secondly, writing out pure machine code like you are doing is horrible, and prone to bugs, if you feel you cannot use the inline assembler provided by your compiler, use something like [AsmJIT](http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/) instead (or any other in-memory assembler).

Your code however works fine however (when called using `__cdecl`), when once those issues are addressed, its still unsafe though. (I ran it and got the expected result of 77, *after* putting it in executable memory). You will likely run into problems down the road with fixing up of virtual and absolute calls/long jumps, which will make this ever *more* complex.

Your crashes on FPU and SSE instructions is mostly likely alignment problems, but its impossible to tell without a system code, your assembly, or what CPU you are using, and in cases like this, its best to use a debugger, such as ollydbg (which is *free*) and step through the code.

---

the semi-corrected code:

```
static char asmRoutine_body[]  =
{

0xC8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,      //enter
0x8B, 0x45, 0x08,          // mov eax, [ebp+8]
0xC9,               //leave
0xC3
};

void* p = (void*)VirtualAlloc(NULL,sizeof(asmRoutine_body),MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
memcpy(p,asmRoutine_body,sizeof(asmRoutine_body));
int ( *asmRoutine)(int, int, int) = ( int (*)(int, int, int))p;
int ret = asmRoutine(77,66,55);
VirtualFree(p,sizeof(asmRoutine_body),MEM_RELEASE);
printf("%d\n",ret);
```

outputs: `77`

Comment: can you explain "Your code however works fine however, (..) I ran it and got the expected result" - does it mean that the example with asmRoutine(77,66,55) works for you? MUCH TNX for alignment suggestion - I use old pentium 4 / Win XP here  (and old borland 55 - works ok for my pure winapi games)

Comment: @user982377: yes, it works fine (I get 77), I'll actually add in the code used. you should seriously consider using a newer compiler....

Comment: maybe but i am using only c and pure winapi and it is not outdated in such area i notiice (compile fast and i like it, got nice editor and so) -- as to asm, tnx for info, I will also try edit my post and include some sse routine which crashes for me, could you also check if it will work on your system?

Comment: as to aligment, i am not sure what i should try to alinn here, though.. arguments pushed on stack?

Comment: @user982377: your `float4` arguments must be aligned to 16-byte boundries, as required by the x86 SSE standards, else you need to use unaligned loads/stores

Comment: ok, tnx, i ve found this, (see edit in initial post) i was trying to set global alignment by compiler switches fount that i got use fastcall and luckily it works excellent now for me (though i know that on some No eXecute systems it will fail - but do not bother now - i need to first try it at home